# "sports.blogoverflow.com" Sounds legit, doesn't it?

Tags: discussion, blog

After taking a look at Stack Exchange and our sister sites, I noticed a few sites have dedicated blogs...even beta sites. With that thought, I wondered if Sports SE can have a blog.

---

I haven't thought much about the content of a blog for Sports SE. However, I see great potential in it.

First, it presents great potential for attention and spotlight toward current/upcoming sporting events, athletes, news, product/equipment reviews, and predictions to name a view...some of which are not constructive in the Q&A format. Imagine not only asking about a particular ruling on Q&A related to a particular occurrence, we can blog about it too!

Next, it presents a great opportunity for journalistic efforts without becoming a member of already popular sites such as Bleacher Report and Yahoo! Sports or becoming an ESPN Insider. If sports journalism is of interest to you (as it is to me), this can be a great place to start.

Furthermore, it presents a way to gain more visibility, attract new users, and encourage community contribution. I know Sports SE is growing, but we can provide more engaging content to the community and beyond with a blog to further grow. It all may work hand-in-hand.

---

So, how do we get a blog started? [Poll the community for interest](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/).

**Are we, the Sports SE Community, interested in setting up and contributing to a blog?**

<sub>In reference to the link above, there are several steps we need to take before we are set up with a blog. This question is to gauge interest.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After interest by means of three upvotes and four contributing volunteers (including myself), I have decided to take the next step and [define the scope and purpose of the blog](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372/a-blog-for-sports-se-sounds-legit-what-will-its-scope-and-purpose-be).

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested in writing blog posts about sports/athletes I am very knowledgeable about. In fact, I am creating my own blog site at the moment and I have written for software magazines in the past.

Comment: There we go. Two contributors.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested in contributing some stuff on advanced statistical research.

Comment: aka Mr. Sabermetric. That brings the contributor count to three.

Answer (score 0):

I will be interested in providing some good links related to the sports(specifically i am a good fan for Cricket,Football,chess,wrestling,boxing and kickboxing)  which we can use in blog.

In any ways i would like to help, how much i can,i am with you.

Comment: Thanks. Four contributors.

Answer (score 0):

Cool initiative... I have already put forth [my opinion on the blog content](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/378/364). I follow European football, and the transfer market associated with it. Particularly Premier League and Champions/Europa League. Depending on the consensus for the content of this speculative blog, I can imagine contributing with articles on football in Europe and [Fantasy Premier League](http://fantasy.premierleague.com/).